# How to suexec public_html/cgi-bin without the "~user/" in url

Tags: apache, cgi, alias, selinux, public-html

Apache 2.4.29 (Fedora)
Perl v5.26.1

I have a website which is run, for several reasons, out of the public_html directory of the user "jaf".  Apache is set up to run cgi scripts in this directory tree as the local user ("jaf").  So, for instance "http://billyard.ca/~jaf/cgi-bin/simpletest.cgi" successfully executes as user "jaf" (rather than the default "apache").  What I am trying to achieve, unsuccessfully so far, is the following:

1. To get apache to run all cgi called by "http://billyard.ca/cgi-bin/" as if they were called by "http://billyard.ca/~jaf/cgi-bin/" (i.e., omit the "~jaf/") yet still operate within the "~jaf/public_html" directory as user "jaf" rather than "apache". I've added the following to the apache configuration:

   `<`VirtualHost *:80`>`
   Servername billyard.ca
   SuexecUserGroup jaf jaf
   DocumentRoot "/home/jaf/public_html"
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/jaf/public_html/cgi-bin/
   `<`/VirtualHost`>`

This works "billyard.ca/~jaf/cgi-bin/simpletest.cgi".
This fails "billyard.ca/cgi-bin/simpletest.cgi"; it gives me a 500 internal server error and suexec reports "command not in docroot".

2. To get selinux to allow this (right now I have to go into permissive mode otherwise I get apache "premature end of header" error messages)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear.